# Class function return "is not a function" when used in instance field

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that extends another class (base in this case) which inherits a translator function like this:

```
export class Details extends base implements IDetails { //translator lies in "base"
}
```

I want to declare a constant or a object more precise. For the value, I need to call a function that returns the translated string. And since I need to use the class/translator function, I need to declare it inside of the class:

```
private readonly data = {
  myString: this.translator('alert'),
  myString2: this.translator('repair'),
}
```

No syntax errors. I run the program and get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.translator is not a function
enter code here
```

My class that I extend

```
export declare class Elem extends base implements IElem {
    private static readonly registeredComponents;
    private static readonly propertyManager;
    static get is(): string;
    localize: ((...args: any[]) => string) | null;
    translator: ((...args: any[]) => string);
    constructor();
    ready(): void;
    connectedCallback(): void;
    disconnectedCallback(): void;
    static get properties(): any;
}
export {};
```

The translator function works in other areas of the code, but in instance fields it does not. How come?

Comment: Do you get a TypeScript error too?

Comment: your code looks fine, could you add your implement of your `translator` function?

Comment: No Typescript errors. Only in runtime an errors returns  via console.

Comment: Added. Also updated with the info that the translator function works in other parts of the code but not in instance fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field initialization happens before the constructor in JS/TS. So you don't have a this to call yet.

Order is:
1.Base class fields
2.Base constructor
3.Derived Fields
4.Derived constructor

So you will have to initialize it in the constructor, or expose it as a lazy loaded field (build value in getter first access)

Comment: Also, note that this isn't just because the class instance isn't initialized yet (you couldn't even call the base class' methods from a derived field declaration), but because the initializer isn't wrapped in a function inside the class, and `this` always bound to the *function* it is used in; in case of class fields, it's the function that the `class` declaration resides in. The getter solves both things, as it *is* a function.